# Show that if G(U, W) is a bipartite graph such that min u∈U degree(u) ≥ max w∈W degree(w), then G has a matching of size |U|.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I'm assuming that for this question |U| $\le$ |W| is implied.

I can intuitively see why this is true; as the degree of each vertex of U is greater or equal to any vertex of W then at worst there exists |U| edges, each between a unique pair $(v_u, v_w)$ for all $v_u$ in U, and hence a matching of size |U| exists, but I'm not sure this is a satisfactory proof.

Does anything need to be added to/reworded in this?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that refers to the degree of the vertex $u$

Comment: @TravisJ - I've changed the notation to make things a bit clearer, thanks for pointing out that this wasn't common notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

- [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).
- Suppose that there exists set $U'\subseteq U$ such that $|U'|>|\mathcal{N}(U')|$, then the average degree in $U'$ is smaller than the average degree in $\mathcal{N}(U')$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Ah, so I should add this: 

As the degree($u$) >= degree($w$) for all $u,w$ we know that all subsets $U' \subseteq U$ are such that $|U'| \leq |N(U')|$ which satisfies Hall's condition, and thus a matching of size $|U|$ exists?

Comment: @Jonathan Yep ;-)